react ts inversify doesn't work with class component
https://github.com/Lavshyak/react-ts-component-class-inversify-problem
Check render() code:
import {useInjection} from "inversify-react";
import {Bar} from "./Bar";
import {Component} from "react";
import SERVICE_IDENTIFIER from "./identifiers";
import container from "./ioc_config";
import getDecorators from "inversify-inject-decorators";

const {lazyInject} = getDecorators(container);
console.log(JSON.stringify(lazyInject))

//it doesn't work
export class FooComponent extends Component
{
    @lazyInject(SERVICE_IDENTIFIER.BAR)
    private readonly bar!: Bar

    render()
    {
        //error: this.bar is undefined
        console.log("bar value: " + this.bar.v);
        return (<div>bar value: {this.bar.v}</div>)
    }
}

//it works
export function FooComponent1()
{
    const bar = useInjection<Bar>(SERVICE_IDENTIFIER.BAR);
    return (<div>bar value: {bar.v}</div>)
}

In render() bar is undefined
Why does this happen? how to make it work?
I tried @inject, @resolve (it throws error about reflection metadata and unsetted emitDecoratorMetadata but it is setted to true).
Constructor in FooComponent did not help:
constructor(p:{},c:{})
    {
        super(p,c);
    }


That is not works because it is frontend)
I changed @lazyInject(SERVICE_IDENTIFIER.BAR) to @resolve(SERVICE_IDENTIFIER.BAR). Now it works
